# ActionScript 3 Object to name value string

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

In a Flex application I am trying to turn an Object into a QueryString such as name1=value1&name2=value2...  But I am having trouble getting the names of the Objects children. How do I enumerate the names instead of the values?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you're doing a `for each(in)` loop.  Just do a normal `for(in)` loop and you'll get the names instead of the values:

```
for(var name:String in obj) {
  var value:* = obj[name];
  // do whatever you need
}
```

Comment: If it's a concrete class instead of just an Object, see ObjectUtil.getClassInfo()

Comment: I believe `for(in)` still works on concrete classes, but it's generally more limited on what it returns.  It will only pick up what those classes have set up as visible using the `setPropertyIsEnumerable` method.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first off, if you need that query string to actually query a server, you don't really need to get it yourself as this code will query the server for you

```
protected function callSerivce():void
{
    var o:Object = new Object();
    o.action = "loadBogusData";
    o.val1 = "dsadasd";
    service.send(o);
}

<mx:HTTPService id="service" url="http://www.somewhere.com/file.php" method="GET" showBusyCursor="true"/>
```

Will make a call to the server like this: http://www.somewhere.com/file.php?action=loadBogusData&val1=dsadasd

But in case you really want to analyze the object by hand, try using ObjectUtil.getClassInfo, it returns a lot of information including all the fields (read more on [LiveDocs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/2/langref/mx/utils/ObjectUtil.html#getClassInfo%28%29)).